# Ruby On Rails - HTML Conditional Based On Controller and Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a syntax issue I'm trying to sort out.  I'm just trying to check if a controller/action is loaded, and if so do something, and if not do something else, seems simple.  This gives me an error:

```
<% if (:controller => 'home', :action => 'index') do %>
    <div class="header">
<% else %>
    <div class="header-2">
<% end %>
```

Can someone assist me with the syntax issue here?  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to modify the if clause like this:

```
<% if controller_name == 'home' && action_name == 'index' %>
```

Additionally, if have to call this more than once, I'd suggest you define a helper.

**application_helper.rb**

```
def home_index?
  controller_name == 'home' && action_name == 'index'
end
```

This way your code will be a lot more readable:

**some_view.html.erb**

```
<div class='<%= home_index? ? "foo" : "bar" %>'>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Rails provided helper to check those kind of things (current controller/action, parameters, ...): `current_page?`

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'index') %>
  <div class="header">
<% else %>
  <div class="header-2">
<% end %>
```

Documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Using this helper you can also check for specific parameters:

```
 current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'index', page: '2')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view, you'll need to check for `controller_name` and `action_name`. Try this

```
<% if controller_name == 'home' && action_name == 'index' %>
    <div class="header">
<% else %>
    <div class="header-2">
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ur view , it will works

```
<% if (controller_name == 'applications' && action_name == 'index') %>
    <div class="header">
<%else%>
    <div class="header-2">
<%end%>
```